# How to Mock Spring Boot Application Context In Unit Testing

Tags: spring-boot

I Have a Source class which has a dependency Of type Application Context. Using this we are achieving polymorphism. How to unit test this class. I'm using Spring boot application.

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;
String beanName= "employeeImpl";

applicationContext.getBean(beanName, Employee.class);
```

Comment: Really shouldn't be autowiring the context to get a bean. Kinda missing the power of the IoC container.

Comment: I would have to agree with @DarrenForsythe; why not immediately `@Autowire` the bean? If it's a bean, it must be a `@Component` or a `@Bean`, so you should be able to `@Autowire` it once the Spring Container is spinned up.

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you are trying to mock a hard-to-mock class, consider using a wrapper class (i.e. the Adapter/Wrapper pattern). For example, one might create new class, `ApplicationContextAdapter` that is auto wired into your class under test as a class that is easy to mock. This new class would internally autowire the actual `ApplicationContext`instance and might have a `getApplicationContext()` method to get the wrapped instance.

That being said, I agree with @DarrenForsythe that you don’t shouldn’t autowire this class.